# How to store a Haskell data type in an Unboxed Vector in continuous memory

Tags: haskell

I would like to store a non-parametric, unpacked data type like

```
data Point3D = Point3D {-# UNPACK #-} !Int {-# UNPACK #-} !Int {-# UNPACK #-} !Int
```

In an Unboxed vector. [Data.Vector.Unboxed](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.1/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html#t%3aMutable) says:

> In particular, unboxed vectors of pairs are represented as pairs of unboxed vectors.

Why is that? I would prefer to have my `Point3D` laid out **one after another** in memory to get fast cache-local access when sequentially iterating  over them - the equivalent of `mystruct[1000]` in C.

Using `Vector.Unboxed` or otherwise, how can I achieve that?

---

By the way: With [vector-th-unbox](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-th-unbox-0.2.0.2/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed-Deriving.html) the same happens, since with that you just transform your data type to the `(Unbox a, Unbox b) => Unbox (a, b)` [instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#g:1).

Comment: Have you considered using Storable instead of Unboxed. I once tested it in a few scenarios and I don't think their performance differs a lot.

Comment: @user1117884 A bit: `Storable` instances are more difficult/boilerplaty to write and I consider `Unboxed` a "purer" vector type - I don't actually want to ever manually `peek` or `poke` into that vector. That said, if what I want is not possible with `Unboxed` and if there is a solution that can keep the Storable boilerplate small (like *vector-th-unbox* does for Unboxed), that would certainly be a solution!

Comment: The documentation means `(Unbox a, Unbox b) => (a, b)` specifically when it says "pairs". For your type, you'll need to write your own `Unbox` instance, and that instance is free to lay things out contiguously if you so desire.

Comment: @nh2: `Storable` instances are definitely less boilerplate to write than `Unboxed`, `Vector`, and `MVector` instances.  Also, I believe `Vector` pairs work the way they do so that zipping/unzipping can be done efficiently.

Comment: Pure speculation: if the types being paired have different sizes (such as `(Int32, Int64)`), the pair-of-vectors approach may avoid alignment problems that could cause poor performance on some architectures.

Comment: @dfeuer the performance impact of caching would probably dominate that. I think the best rule is if the data is used together, store it together.

Comment: @JustinRaymond, that is certainly a reasonable concern (I've raised it myself). Heavy non-sequential access will waste cache lines. On the other hand, combining, say, `Int64` with `Word8` would make for very bad performance in common cases, wasting memory. I'm also not sure how other approaches could be implemented flexibly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know why vectors of pairs are stored as pairs of vectors, but you can easily write instances for your datatype to store the elements sequentially.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as G 
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as M 
import Control.Monad (liftM, zipWithM_)
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base

data Point3D = Point3D {-# UNPACK #-} !Int {-# UNPACK #-} !Int {-# UNPACK #-} !Int

newtype instance MVector s Point3D = MV_Point3D (MVector s Int)
newtype instance Vector    Point3D = V_Point3D  (Vector    Int)
instance Unbox Point3D
```

At this point the last line will cause an error since there are no instances for vector types for `Point3D`. They can be written as follows:

```
instance M.MVector MVector Point3D where 
  basicLength (MV_Point3D v) = M.basicLength v `div` 3 
  basicUnsafeSlice a b (MV_Point3D v) = MV_Point3D $ M.basicUnsafeSlice (a*3) (b*3) v 
  basicOverlaps (MV_Point3D v0) (MV_Point3D v1) = M.basicOverlaps v0 v1 
  basicUnsafeNew n = liftM MV_Point3D (M.basicUnsafeNew (3*n))
  basicUnsafeRead (MV_Point3D v) n = do 
    [a,b,c] <- mapM (M.basicUnsafeRead v) [3*n,3*n+1,3*n+2]
    return $ Point3D a b c 
  basicUnsafeWrite (MV_Point3D v) n (Point3D a b c) = zipWithM_ (M.basicUnsafeWrite v) [3*n,3*n+1,3*n+2] [a,b,c]

instance G.Vector Vector Point3D where 
  basicUnsafeFreeze (MV_Point3D v) = liftM V_Point3D (G.basicUnsafeFreeze v)
  basicUnsafeThaw (V_Point3D v) = liftM MV_Point3D (G.basicUnsafeThaw v)
  basicLength (V_Point3D v) = G.basicLength v `div` 3
  basicUnsafeSlice a b (V_Point3D v) = V_Point3D $ G.basicUnsafeSlice (a*3) (b*3) v 
  basicUnsafeIndexM (V_Point3D v) n = do 
    [a,b,c] <- mapM (G.basicUnsafeIndexM v) [3*n,3*n+1,3*n+2]
    return $ Point3D a b c
```

I think most of the function definitions are self explanatory. The vector of points is stored as a vector of `Int`s and the `n`th point is the `3n`,`3n+1`,`3n+2` `Int`s.

Comment: A few questions about this: 1) I think the `b` in `basicUnsafeSlice` is a length argument, so shouldn't it be `b*3`? 2) [Docs for `basicOverlaps`, `basicUnsafeNew` etc. suggest](https://github.com/haskell/vector/blob/0e8a0ec/Data/Vector/Generic/Mutable.hs#L95) `overlaps` and `unsafeNew` be called instead - should that also be done for this instance? They don't seem to give a reason for it. 3) What do you do when there's not only `Int`s in your record? What to choose as underlying representation (i.e. alternative to `V_Point3D (Vector Int)`?

Comment: @nh2 `basicUnsafeSlice a b` returns a vector starting at the `a`th element and ending at the `b`th element. The start of the `n`th element is `3*n`; the end is `3*n+2`. 2) You never use these functions, but they are used to define all other functions on unboxed vectors, so these are all the functions you need to define to use any function on unboxed vectors. 3) Your "point" type should contain `n` elements of the same type. This would work with `data Point3D a = P3d {-# UNPACK #-} !a {-# UNPACK #-} !a {-# UNPACK #-} !a` and `newtype instance MVector s (Point3D a) = MV_Point3D (MVector s a)`

Comment: 1) The [docs claim though](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.1/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html#v:basicUnsafeSlice) that the second argument is a *length* argument, not an end index. 2) Ok. 3) Yes, this answers my original question, but what I meant with this comment was: What if your record does not contain `n` of elements of the same type, but instead something like `data Mystruct = Mystruct { id :: Word64, position :: Point3D, visible :: Bool, use :: MyEnum }`? So a record with members of different size. In this case, not sure what to pick as underlying vector...

Comment: 1) Woops! I guess I should read more carefully. Nice catch. 3) You could do this, but you would need to have way of serializing and deserializing `MyStruct` to a more uniform type. You could use a mature library like `Data.Serialize` or roll your own if you have specific needs.

Comment: Also, there is `Data.Vector.Storable` which seems to be precisely for this sort of thing: vectors of types that live in contiguous memory. Writing `Storable` instances will probably be the easiest path.

Comment: Yes, I know about `Storable` vectors, but I do not care about defining the *exact* C-style memory layout, and was somehow thinking that with unboxed vectors I could have the vector library automatically figure out a correct packed, contiguous representation without writing the low-level representation myself. Looks like I was a bit off with this expectation! However, having a solution for heterogenous records like Point3D is already very useful.

Comment: You can derive instances of `Data.Serialize` by deriving `Generic`, then write your own vector instances which store the data as `ByteString`, which is really just a `ForeignPtr`.